# Error thrown when creating a new project Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-community

I've recently uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio Community 2015 and now when I try to create a new project this error is thrown:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.ProjectCreation.Contracts, Version = 14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've just reinstall Visual Studio, should it be a framework problem? I'm thinking in uninstall and reinstall some framework versions, should I? Why is this happening?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm not sure that's the issue here - OP says he gets the error _"when I try to create a new project"_  - the question title is misleading..

Comment: @EdPlunkett In what way does that solve the error? The OP is just creating a new project in VS, he/she is not adding a dll or trying to load a dll in code.

Comment: Thanks guys, my bad

Comment: Should I try uninstalling and reinstalling .net framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reset Windows 10 and now it works, it was all because I was trying to install ASP.net Core downloading `DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.2` and installing it separately, then ASP.net Core was not working properly, I was trying some things by myself and probably I did something I shouldn't do and Visual Studio wasn't working properly. Once reinstalled Windows 10, I installed ASP.net Core using the template that gives Visual Studio(Add ASP.net 5 RC2 or something like that) and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: make sure you are running as an administrator

Step 2: if step 1 fails, repair your Visual Studio installation (navigate to programs, click on Visual Studio, select repair).

Step 3: Make sure you're applied all updates to Visual Studio

Okay: I know these are common sense but we all get tired and miss "the obvious"

Comment: Okay, I added "step 3". Is it "all projects" or only certain project types. For example... If it was ASP.NET, I'd disable/re-enable IIS for Windows, etc.

Comment: I've tried that too and nothing, finally I had to reset Windows 10 and after that is working properly now

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving "Exception HResult **0x800540402**" when trying to create a new project in Visual Studio 2022.

The solution turned out to be an **extension** **problem**!

In my case it was "Incredibuild" I had disabled it some time ago maybe 3 months. Apparently one of the recent updates created a situation where this was not allowed.  I reenabled it and all was well.

BTW; I could create one or two types of projects but the majoriry gave the "Exception HResult **0x800540402**" error.